# Let $f:A \to \Bbb R$, where $A \subset \Bbb R^n$. Assume $\{x \in A : f(x) < q\}$ is measurable for all $q \in \Bbb Q$. Show that $A$ is measurable.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> Let $f:A \to \Bbb R$, where $A \subset \Bbb R^n$. Assume that $\{x \in A : f(x) < q\}$ is measurable for all $q \in \Bbb Q$. Show that $A$ is measurable.

I initially tought about Caratheodory's criterion for the measurability of $A$, but that doesn't seem to  help here. Should I consider the preimage $f^{-1}(-\infty, q)$ somehow to get access to the measurability of $A$? Also is it of help here that the rationals are of measure zero?

Comment: Rational numbers form a countable set. Use the definition of measurable sets to show that $A$ is measurable

Comment: You could for example write $A=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\{x\in A : f(x)<n\}$

Comment: And this is countable since the naturals are countable? @Momo

Comment: @Timur Yes, it is countable union of measurable sets.